# bash while read executes once and doesn't match my regex

Tags: bash

This is `file.txt`:

```
G9DG1.fqdn.com
G9DG2.fqdn.com
G9DG3.fqdn.com
G9DG4.fqdn.com
G9DC1.fqdn.com
G9DC3.fqdn.com
G9DG5.fqdn.com
G9DC4.fqdn.com
```

This is the `while read` to check if line mathces with my regex:

```
while read -r line
do
    if [[ "$line" == "$(grep -E 'G[0-9]{1,2}[DS][C][0-9]{1,3}.fqdn.com')" ]]

    then
        echo "$line matches"
    else
        echo "$line doesn't match"
    fi
done < file.txt
```

It only prints:

```
G9DG1.fqdn.com doesn't match
```

The issue is it only runs one iteration and exits. While I need to check if the hostname equals to the provided regex, line by line.

Designed output:

```
G9DG1.fqdn.com doesn't match
G9DG2.fqdn.com doesn't match
G9DG3.fqdn.com doesn't match
G9DG4.fqdn.com doesn't match
G9DC1.fqdn.com matches
G9DC3.fqdn.com matches
G9DG5.fqdn.com doesn't match
G9DC4.fqdn.com matches
```

Comment: @Saeed I have already fixed your issue! Did you check my answer?you can use the `=~` operator in the `[[ ... ]]` construct to perform regular expression matching!

Comment: @Freeman yes sir, that worked. I see I shouldn't have used `grep` and matching the starting and ending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this out :

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    if [[ "$line" =~ ^(G[0-9]{1,2}[DS][C][0-9]{1,3}\.fqdn\.com)$ ]]
    then
        echo "$line matches"
    else
        echo "$line doesn't match"
    fi
done < file.txt
```

output :

```
G9DG1.fqdn.com doesn't match
G9DG2.fqdn.com doesn't match
G9DG3.fqdn.com doesn't match
G9DG4.fqdn.com doesn't match
G9DC1.fqdn.com matches
G9DC3.fqdn.com matches
G9DG5.fqdn.com doesn't match
G9DC4.fqdn.com matches
```

ok I also add another solution with `awk` !

```
awk '/^(G[0-9]{1,2}[DS][C][0-9]{1,3}\.fqdn\.com)$/ {print $0 " matches"; next} {print $0 " doesn'\''t match"}' file.txt
```

Comment: FYI if you use `\047` instead of `'\''` then your awk script will work as-is whether interpreted on the command line like now or if you later copy/paste it into a file to execute with `awk -f` (e.g. if you want to expand it to do more). See http://awk.freeshell.org/PrintASingleQuote for more info on this.

Comment: @EdMorton thnx, It's interesting, I had written it with awk, but since I wasn't paying attention to POSIX, I switched to the loop method. It doesn't matter! Just the fact that you learn something each time is valuable!

Comment: you right about the performance and simplicity advantages of `awk`over loops for text processing.but,there are certain situations where using a shell loop may be preferred or even necesary,for instane,if you are working on a system that lacks`awk`or if your task requires implemenitng intricate logic that is more easily achieved with shel scripting,and,shell loops offer greater flexibilty in terms of integration with other shel commands and tools.it is important to conider these factors and choose the most suitable approach based on the specific requirements and constraints of the task at hand!

Comment: @EdMorton The text above was in response to a comment that you deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this with a shell loop, see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Efficiently, robustly, and portably using 1 call to any POSIX awk (POSIX compliance required for the regexp intervals `{1,2}` and `{1,3}`):

```
$ awk '{print $0, (/^(G[0-9]{1,2}[DS]C[0-9]{1,3}\.fqdn\.com)$/ ? "matches" : "doesn\047t match")}' file.txt
G9DG1.fqdn.com doesn't match
G9DG2.fqdn.com doesn't match
G9DG3.fqdn.com doesn't match
G9DG4.fqdn.com doesn't match
G9DC1.fqdn.com matches
G9DC3.fqdn.com matches
G9DG5.fqdn.com doesn't match
G9DC4.fqdn.com matches
```

If you aren't using a POSIX-compliant awk then get a new awk as you're missing important functionality that's been around in most awks since about the year 2000.

By the way, the reason your code only looped once is that you've redirected input to come from `file.txt` so when you do `grep ...` THAT is where it's getting it's input from. So the first `read` reads the first line of `file.txt` then the `grep` reads the rest of `file.txt` and prints the lines from it that match the regexp, then the `if` compares that grep output to the current contents of `$line` and finds they are not the same string, then the loop exits as there's no input left to read.

Comment: output is wrong and just showing `doesn't match` !

Comment: @Freeman the output is exactly as I show in my answer which is exactly the expected output from the question. If that's not what you see then you aren't using a POSIX awk. I edited my answer to state why it has to be a POSIX compliant awk.